# Two sticky divs in different directions

Tags: html, css, scroll, sticky

I'm trying to make an interface where two parts overlap, and one can scroll through the first part horizontally and the second part vertically. I quickly discovered the css sticky position.

Here is code demonstrating the issue I encountered using `position: sticky;` :

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

#d1 {
  background: red;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  width: 2000px;
  height: 50px;
  opacity: 0.8;
}

#d2 {
  background: blue;
  position: sticky;
  left: 0;
  width: 50px;
  height: 2000px;
  opacity: 0.8;
}
```

```html
<div id="d1"></div>
<div id="d2"></div>
```

(doesn't work in my browser, here is a jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/2bovgy84/1/ )

If you scroll down red div stays on top (what I expect), but if you scroll right blue div gets "stuck" half-way through (but I expect it to behave like the red one does)

I do not understand this behavior, at all.

Comment: You are required to post a [mcve] here, **within your question**, and not a link to your site or any third party site.

Comment: I didn't know that, fixed it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

body needs to be allowed to grow wider than HTML/window's width so it doesn't  drag the blue element along with it (backgrounds on html/body shows what happens : https://jsfiddle.net/Lq473pue/1/ ).

you can use for that:

- `display:inline-block;`
- `display:table;`
- `float:left;`

jsfiddle updated : https://jsfiddle.net/Lq473pue/

`min-width:100%;` can also be handy for body

Answer (score 1):

The body needs the width or you need elements that are not sticky to create that width. Otherwise your body will be the width of the viewport.

https://jsfiddle.net/y9r74c0x/20/

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  width: 2000px;
}

#d1 {
  background: red;
  position: sticky;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 2000px;
  height: 50px;
  opacity: 0.8;
}

#d2 {
  background: blue;
  position: sticky;
  right: 0;
  width: 50px;
  height: 2000px;
  opacity: 0.8;
}
```

```html
<div id="d1"></div>
<div id="d2"></div>
```